# Migrating Apache rewrites to Nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to serve static HTML with server side PHP processing with Nginx. I have no experience with Apache. I would like to migrate the following re-writes from Apache's .htaccess to Nginx. What would be the corresponding rewrites for a server or location block in Nginx's default.conf?

```
#.htaccess
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(min\-merge\-cache)=(css|js)\/(.*)$ /static-server/min-merge-cache.php?   files=$3&format=$2 [NC,L,NS]

RewriteRule ^$ /static-server/file-server.php?file=index&ext=html [NC,L,NS]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(js|css|html|htm)$ /static-server/file-server.php?file=$1&ext=$2   [NC,L,NS]
RewriteRule ^(images)\/(.*)\.(jpe?g|gif|ico|png|swf|flv)$ /static-server/file-  server.php?file=$1/$2&ext=$3&img=1 [NC,L,NS]
FileETag None
</IfModule>

php_flag zlib.output_compression On
```

My current default.conf looks like this:

```
server {
listen               8080;
port_in_redirect     off;
add_header           Cache-Control public;
expires              max;
server_name          www.mydomain.com;  
root                 /usr/share/nginx/www;
index                index.html index.php;

#Rewrites
rewrite ^(min\-merge\-cache)=(css|js)\/(.*)$ /static-server/min-merge-cache.php?files=$3&format=$2;

location = /favicon.ico {
   return 204;
  }
location = /index.html {
    return 301 http://www.mydomain.com/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
}

#Client Cache
gzip on;
gzip_types text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;

location ~ \.(css|js|htc)$ {
expires 1y;
}

location ~ \.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
expires 1y;
}

location ~ \. (asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|m id|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png |pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw |zip)$ {
expires 1y;
}

## All errors get the generic error page
  error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 495 496 497
             500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 /error_page.html;
  location  /404.html {
      internal;
  }
}
```

I have spent the day reading the documentation at Nginx - http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule and the documentation at Apache - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html but it has only culminated into horror and despair. I seek your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(min\-merge\-cache)=(css|js)\/(.*)$ /static-server/min-merge-cache.php?files=$3&format=$2 [NC,L,NS]
RewriteRule ^$ /static-server/file-server.php?file=index&ext=html [NC,L,NS]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(js|css|html|htm)$ /static-server/file-server.php?file=$1&ext=$2   [NC,L,NS]
RewriteRule ^(images)\/(.*)\.(jpe?g|gif|ico|png|swf|flv)$ /static-server/file-server.php?file=$1/$2&ext=$3&img=1 [NC,L,NS]
```

would translate to:

```
rewrite ^(min\-merge\-cache)=(css|js)\/(.*)$ /static-server/min-merge-cache.php?files=$3&format=$2 last;
rewrite ^$ /static-server/file-server.php?file=index&ext=html last;
rewrite ^(.*)\.(js|css|html|htm)$ /static-server/file-server.php?file=$1&ext=$2 last;
rewrite ^(images)\/(.*)\.jpe?g|gif|ico|png|swf|flv)$ /static-server/file-server.php?file=$1/$2&ext=$3&img=1 last;
```